# С# работа с реестром

Tags: c#, реестр

Требуется получить данные по умолчанию из реестра. Цель в том что бы достать Current system local, но не получется так как в реестре по умолчанию "Default" 2 записи и мне нужна именно вторая запись.

Реестр:

```
RegistryKey curl_lang = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\Locale");
string curl_lang_dump = curl_lang.GetValue("").ToString();
```

Получаю первое значение Default, а второе не могу. 
Пример с foreach:

```
string softwareRegLoc = @"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\";

        RegistryKey regKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(softwareRegLoc, false);

        foreach (string subKeyName in regKey.GetSubKeyNames())
        {
            RegistryKey subKey = regKey.OpenSubKey(subKeyName);

            if(subKey.ToString() == @"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\Locale")
            {
                foreach(string a in subKey.GetValue(""))
                {
                    string softwareName =  a.ToString();
                    Console.WriteLine(softwareName+"test");
                }
            }   
        }
```

Comment: А что означает «не получается»? Объясните подробнее, в какой момент и какая происходит ошибка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего у вас ошибка

> Оператор foreach не работает с переменными типа "object", так как "object" не содержит открытого определения для "GetEnumerator".

потому что subKey имеет единственное значение (а не список).

```
string softwareRegLoc = @"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\";

            RegistryKey regKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(softwareRegLoc, false);

            foreach (string subKeyName in regKey.GetSubKeyNames())
            {
                RegistryKey subKey = regKey.OpenSubKey(subKeyName);

                if (subKey.ToString() == @"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\Locale")
                {
                    var i = subKey.GetValue("");
                    Console.WriteLine(i);

                    //foreach (string a in subKey.GetValue(""))
                    //{
                    //  string softwareName = a.ToString();
                    //  Console.WriteLine(softwareName + "test");

                    //}
                }


            }
```

Получаем Current system local `00000419`

А что у вас дальше не получается - непонятно. Какую вам вторую запись нужно?

Если вы хотите получить Default то добавьте

```
var i2 = subKey.GetValue("(Default)");
```

Comment: Спасибо , сработало `var i2 = subKey.GetValue("(Default)");`